# regex match part of file path if key not present

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to match part of a file path if it does not include a certain keyword using regular expressions in python. For example, applying the regular expression to "/exclude/this/test/other" should not match, whereas "/this/test/other" should return the file path excluding "other", i.e. "/this/test", and where "other" is any directory. So far I am using this

```
In [153]: re.findall("^(((?!exclude).)*(?=test).*)?", "/exclude/this/test/other")
Out[153]: [('', '')]

re.findall("^(((?!exclude).)*(?=test).*)?", "/this/test/other")
Out[152]: [('/this/test/other', '/')]
```

but I can't get it to stop matching after "test", also there are some empty matches. Any ideas?

Comment: Is what you're looking for always going to be a fixed string, or can it be a pattern?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're getting the extra result because (1) you're using `findall()` instead of `search()`, and (2) you're using capturing groups instead of non-capturing

```
>>> import re
>>> re.search(r'^(?:(?:(?!exclude).)*(?=test)*)$', "/this/test").group(0)
'/this/test'
```

This will work with `findall()` too, but that doesn't really make sense when you're matching the whole string.  More importantly, the *include* part of your regex doesn't work.  Check this:

```
>>> re.search(r'^(?:(?:(?!exclude).)*(?=test)*)$', "/this/foo").group(0)
'/this/foo'
```

That's because the `*` in `(?=test)*` makes the lookahead optional, which makes it pointless.  But getting rid of the `*` isn't really a solution, because `exclude` and `test` might be part of longer words, like `excludexx` or `yyytest`.  Here's a better regex:

```
r'^(?=.*/test\b)(?!.*/exclude\b)(?:/\w+)+$'
```

tested:

```
>>> re.search(r'^(?=.*/test\b)(?!.*/exclude\b)(?:/\w+)+$', '/this/test').group()
'/this/test'
>>> re.search(r'^(?=.*/test\b)(?!.*/exclude\b)(?:/\w+)+$', '/this/foo').group()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'
```

**EDIT:** I see you fixed the "optional lookahead" problem, but now the whole regex is optional!

**EDIT:** If you want it to stop matching after `/test`, try this:

```
r'^(?:/(?!test\b|exclude\b)\w+)*/test\b'
```

`(?:/(?!test\b|exclude\b)\w+)*` matches zero or more path components, as long as they're not `/test` or `/exclude`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your explanation and sorry about my poor regex skills. This looks like it is doing what I need, but how can I make it stop matching after "test", so that "other" is not matched?

Comment: That actually makes the problem a little simpler.  See my edit.

Answer (score 2):

just use `in` if you only need to chek if a keyword is there:

```
In [33]: s1="/exclude/this/test"

In [34]: s2="this/test"

In [35]: 'exclude' in s1
Out[35]: True

In [36]: 'exclude' in s2
Out[36]: False
```

EDIT:
or if you want the path until test only:

```
if 'exclude' not in s:
    re.findall(r'(.+test)',s)
```

Comment: Thanks, but I realise I didn't phrase my question properly, I have edited it, to make things clearer.

Comment: edited the answer to get the path only to 'test' as this seems to be what you want. it's still easier to do it all using regex...

Answer (score 1):

If your match is more complex than could be done with `in` and a simple keyword, it might be more clear if you did two regexs:

```
import re
s1="/exclude/this/test"
s2="this/test"

for s in (s1,s2):
    if re.search(r'exclude',s): 
        print 'excluding:',s
        continue
    print s, re.findall(r'test',s)
```

Prints:

```
excluding: /exclude/this/test
this/test ['test']
```

You can make two regexes compact if that is your goal:

```
print [(s,re.findall(r'test',s)) for s in s1,s2 if not re.search(r'exclude',s)]
```

**Edit**

If I understand your edit, this works:

```
s1="/exclude/this/test/other"
s2="/this/test/other"

print [(s,re.search(r'(.*?)/[^/]+$',s).group(1)) for s in s1,s2 if not re.search(r'exclude',s)]
```

Prints:

```
[('/this/test/other', '/this/test')]
```

Comment: Thanks, but this isn't quite what I am trying to do, I have rephrased my question accordingly.